# Whats should be slideable right panel name which consist of two tabs Search and filter options?

Tags: usability, names

I have a slideable right panel, which has two tabs: search and filter. These two tabs have form fields which allow users to refine their search result displayed in the main section. The options I came up with are the following: Refine Panel and Refine Results. I also want to reuse the name of this panel for places where users can find tools and filters in the application.

Comment: Is the panel used to generate the search results displayed in the main section? Or are these results generated by another UI component?

Answer (score 1):

"Refine" is used quite commonly for this. If you have enough space then "Search & Filter" may be a better option since it exactly describes what's hidden behind the button.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a bit more clarity in your use case might be helpful. But if I understand correctly you want to provide search and filter in a slide in panel.

My first thought is that this might not be the best pattern to use. Most often I see Search as either an option on the main list screen, or a separate screen of its own... but not as a modal element on top of the main screen (such as a slide-in panel). Either way, the results usually show up in the main screen.

The FILTERS, however, can be presented in a slide-in panel - a fairly common pattern. In fact, I designed an app that worked just that way. The main list was shown on the main screen, searching could happen on that screen, and filters were in a hideaway panel that slid out (effectively) from the right:

[image]

Does this pattern make sense for your app?